# the value from unit testing not found

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

I am beginner with unit testing. I have class for testing and the value not show. I don't know root cause from. the value transaction time not show. I don't really understand for this code. Maybe you can give me explanation why the value not show. the code:

class testing:

```
@Test
public void Testing2() throws Exception {
    RequestEmailTO requestEmailTo = new RequestEmailTO();
    Date transDate = DateUtil.now();
    Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
    requestEmailTo.setTransactionTime(DateUtil.formatDateToStr(transDate, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"));

    List<NameValuePair> result = SendEmailRequestGenerator.generateRequest(maps);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

RequestEmailTO:

```
public class RequestEmailTO extends RequestBaseFormParamTO{

    @FormParam("processCode")
    private String processCode;
    @FormParam("tos")
    private String to;
    @FormParam("ccs")
    private String cc;
    @FormParam("bccs")
    private String bcc;
    @FormParam("subject")
    private String subject;
    @FormParam("message")
    private String message;
    @FormParam("chdrNum")
    private String chdrNum;
    @FormParam("policyHolder")
    private String policyHolder;
    @FormParam("agentType")
    private String agentType;
    @FormParam("agentName")
    private String agentName;
    @FormParam("emailAgent")
    private String emailAgent;
    @FormParam("replyTo")
    private String replyTo;
    // setter and getter
    }
```

RequestBaseFormParamTO :

```
public class RequestBaseFormParamTO extends BaseFormParamTO {
    @FormParam("channelId")
    private String channelId;
    @FormParam("signatureString")
    private String signatureString;
    // setter and getter
}
```

SendEmailRequestGenerator:

```
public class SendEmailRequestGenerator {
public static List<NameValuePair> generateRequest(Map<String, String> maps){

        List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair( 
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.TO, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.TO)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.SUBJECT, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.SUBJECT)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.CC, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.CC)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.BCC, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.BCC)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.MESSAGE, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.MESSAGE)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.TRANSACTION_ID, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.TRANSACTION_ID)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.TRANSACTION_TIME, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.TRANSACTION_TIME)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.CHANNEL_ID, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.CHANNEL_ID)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.SIGNATURE_STRING, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.SIGNATURE_STRING)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.PROCESS_CODE, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.PROCESS_CODE)));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.REPLY_TO, maps.get(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.REPLY_TO)));

        return parameters;
    }
}
```

the result:
[tos, subject, ccs, bccs, message, transactionId, transactionTime, channelId, signatureString, processCode, replyTo]

Comment: I don't know what your `BasicNameValuePair` class is, but it seems to me that its `toString` method prints only the `name`, not the `value`.  Have a look at `toString` in `BasicNameValuePair` (or one of its superclasses) to see what's going on.  Or post it here if you can't work it out.

Comment: BasicNameValuePair class imported from org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair, I think the value is set with "maps.get" . in left side for name, right side for value. is it true? I need the explaination. thanks

Comment: As per my answer, your test code is not doing anything reasonable. Very simple debugging would show you that you pass empty map to generator, giving you an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test, you set requestEmailTo field:

```
requestEmailTo.setTransactionTime(DateUtil.formatDateToStr(transDate, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"));
```

But you pass empty maps to generator:

```
result = SendEmailRequestGenerator.generateRequest(maps);
```

That's why result does not have transaction time set.
One way to get some output would be to call

```
maps.put(ApplicationConstanta.EmailConstanta.TRANSACTION_TIME, DateUtil.formatDateToStr(transDate, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"))
```

before calculating result